# The probability of "at least two"

Tags: probability, probability-theory

To determine the probability of "at least two" outcomes, we can calculate it by subtracting the probability of "none" outcome from 1. In other words, it's the complement of the probability that no success occurs.

$P(\text{at least one}) = 1 - P(\text{none})$

However, there is one case.
Consider a scenario where there are $N$ distinct samples available, and each sample can be selected multiple times, with repetitions allowed. The size of selected items is also $N$ samples. So, the probability of being selected for each item is

$P = \frac{1}{N}$

While that of not being selected is

$P = 1 - \frac{1}{N}$

Then, in this case, the probability for each item to be
included once or more is given by

$P(\text{at least one}) = 1 - P(\text{none})$

where $P(\text{none}) = (1 - \frac{1}{N})^N$

I am not sure whether my approach is correct, also I want determine another case when the probability for each item to be included twice or more.

Comment: In a probability problem, I normally interpret "at least two" to be represented by $$1 - p(\text{none}) - p(\text{exactly one}).$$

Comment: (1) The Question Post is mixing up "at least 1" & "at least 2". That should be rectified (2) In general , we have "at least1" = "all cases" - "none" (3) More-over , we have "at least 2" = "all cases" - "Exactly 1" - "none" (4) When OP clarifies the Issue , we might know where the Confusion lies